# Check if something exists in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a little problem coding if statement in wordpress.
My plugin stores custom registration fields in one single row in database, lets say "custom_fields". When I print custom_fields using get_user_meta I got an array of all information stored there, eg:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [invoice_company_name] => x [invoice_nip] => x [invoice_street] => x [invoice_street_number] => x [invoice_post_code] => x [invoice_city] => x [invoice_country] => x [birth_date] => x [birth_city] => x [district] => x ) )
```

I want to check if all fields starting with invoice exists. Of course where are the 'x' there are real values.

Well I found function in_array(), so tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_ID, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields', false );
print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
if (in_array("[invoice_company_name]", $all_meta_for_user)) {
echo "exist";} else {echo 'dont exist';}
```

And I got 'dont exist' :) What's going wrong?
Also, can I check all the values at once? Something like in_array([1st]&&[2nd]&&[3rd])?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove brackets : `in_array("[invoice_company_name]", $all_meta_for_user))` to `in_array("invoice_company_name", $all_meta_for_user))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is multi-dimensional, you could search by key using **[array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists)** :

```
foreach($all_meta_for_user as $key=>$val){
  if (array_key_exists('invoice_company_name', $val)) 
    {
      echo "exist in key ".$key;
    } 
  else 
    {
      echo "does not exist in key ".$key;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/130146)**

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
if (in_array("invoice_company_name", $all_meta_for_user[0])) {
```